# AS3 determine differnce between animated and not-animated gif?

Tags: image-manipulation, actionscript-3

Is there a way in AS3 to determine the difference between animated and not-animated gif?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native Flash Player does NOT support animated GIFs. However someone has written a library that does, so you could use that library to read in the file, and count the number of frames. 1 frame = non animated. More than 1 frame = animated.

[AS3 GIF Player Class](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=95)